# Intersection of a facet and a plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

Let's say there is a 3D printer loading a facet with 3 vertexes and a normal:

$$
F: \begin{cases}
\text{vertexes:}~~ (x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2),(x_3,y_3,z_3) \\
\text{normal:}~~ (n_x,n_y,n_z)
\end{cases}
$$

When printing the facet at $z_h$ ($z$ of the printer header), the header should follow a line in the plane of

$$
S: \begin{cases}
z=z_h
\end{cases}
$$

The result is a line segment starting from point $A$ to $B$.

$$
S ~\cap~F=\text{line_segment}(A,B)
$$

I am looking for a method which obtains $A$ and $B$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the vertices by $z$-coordinate. Some simple range checks will then tell you which edges intersect the plane for a given $z$-value, and the intersection points can be found by linear interpolation.

Comment: Looking for $A=..., B=...$ answer.

Comment: @ar2015 Prroducing such a formula is junior-high, if not grade-school, level math. I encourage you to work the rest out for yourself.

Comment: I do not care which grade it is. Looking for a false safe solution to implement on a 3D printer.